# Android Geocode class

Tags: android, maps, geocode

In which library Geocode class is located on android. Does it depend on type of device, cause I have a code which pulls location name like this:

```
List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

And on tablet this code works great, but when it comes to the phone related devices, it just returns empty list.
Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android documentation [Android: GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

> the Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.

According to the documentation it has been there since API level 1 but the recommended way is to call isPresent to see if methods `getFromLocation` and `getFromLocationName` are implemented.